# Conectar Informix .NET via DSN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, informix

Boa tarde,

Estou ha dias tentando conectar uma aplicação a uma base de dados do Informix, porem não consigo de jeito nenhum.

Estou com o Visual Studio 2017 utilizando o ASP.NET Framework 4.6. Tentei achar soluções no site da IBM, mas aquele site não ajuda em muita coisa, tudo fica espalhado e acaba ficando mais confuso ainda.

Tenho instalada a SDK 4.10.FC12 e consegui montar uma conexão através do Administrador de fonte de dados ODBC (nativo do windows)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha pergunta é: como posso acessar essa conexão DSN via visual studio na aplicação .NET?

Se alguém souber, por favor me ajude! Obrigada :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar uma conexão utilizando `odbconnection` :

```
 OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(@"DSN=suaconexaoodbc;UID={usuario};PWD={senha};");
```

Mais informações:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Oi Lucas, 
Estou tentando usar esse exemplo e logo abaixo dessa linha eu coloco a conn.Open(). O problema é que o programa para e fala que a variável conn não existe no contexto, então nem deixa eu executar o programa. Você sabe como posso fazer para resolver isso?

Comment: mostra seu código, atualiza ele na pergunta

Comment: Na verdade, era só montar um construtor e deixar tudo em métodos (desculpe as perguntas, estou começando a programar agora). Obrigada pela ajuda!